# Selenium: How do i upload a photo and insert it in the email?

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver, gmail

I want to insert a photo in a mail (gmail) by automation in Selenium.
I can attach an photo, so that is no problem.

The problem is when i come to this screen and want to change to the Upload tab. I can't find the correct findElement-question.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYeIK.jpg)

I have tried these, but dont get it to work:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("Upload")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//textarea[@name='Upload']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To do that first switch to frame i.e

```
WebElement framename=driver.findElement(By.id("amtponuhel03"));
driver.switchTo().frame(frameElement);
```

> Then pass xpath of upload element to upload

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=':7']/div[.='Upload']"));
```

this should work

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
But the namne of the iframe is different every time.
Is it a better way to identify the frame? Thanks!

Comment: @Fredrik yes you can try xpath  
//iframe[@allow='camera']
this will work